# Convert Pod Frameworks to latest Swift Version

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

When using Xcode's automatic conversion to the latest swift syntax, what is the protocol on converting 3rd party framework targets?

From what I remember from previous conversions, I would opt to convert to swift X.X and the dialogue box that would appear would only have my project target preselected for conversion. However, when I go to convert to Swift 4.2, all of the cocoa pod frameworks I am utilizing are preselected.

It got me wondering what is the protocol for converting to the latest swift versions? If there is one that is...

Comment: You shouldn't modify code of 3rd party frameworks, since that would make updating them quite difficult. Just wait for the maintainer of the framework to update it to the latest Swift version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no protocol. All targets which are compiled with Swift 4.1 and lower will be listed in the conversion dialog box.

**Uncheck all pods**.

It's not required to convert all targets. In Xcode 10 each target can be compiled separately with Swift 3, 4, or 4.2. If you get errors in the pods after building make sure that the *Swift Language Version* is set to Swift 4 (or even 3) in Build Settings of the pod targets.